# Getting error while playing Audio file from S3 buckets in Alexa skill with python SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

While using Audio file from S3 bucket getting error and skill showing problem.

```
import logging
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def create_presigned_url(object_name):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object with a capped expiration of 60 
     seconds

    :param object_name: string
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         region_name=os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_REGION'),
                         config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4',s3= 
                                                      {'addressing_style': 'path'}))
    try:
       bucket_name = os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET')#"aaudiobucket"
       print(bucket_name)
       response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                        'Key': object_name},
                                                         ExpiresIn=300)
    except ClientError as e:
       logging.error(e)
       return None

 #The response contains the presigned URL
 return response

class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
   def can_handle(self, handler_input):
      # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
      return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        
        mp3_url = create_presigned_url("Trimmed_calm_music.mp3")
        print(mp3_url)
        # speak_output = "Whats going on?"
        speak_output = f" </speak> Please listen this audio clip: <audio 
                        src='{mp3_url}'/> </speak>" 
    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            .response
    )
```

From this code i am getting mp3_url from S3 bucket file but audio is not playing.
When I hit URL manually getting error as :

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<X-Amz-Expires>300</X-Amz-Expires>
<Expires>2023-12-18T15:38:17Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2023-12-18T17:16:25Z</ServerTime>
<RequestId>GWWSAT3EM9XT2STD</RequestId>
<HostId>1Itsk7kIaAsidH3+v3fGy6W6WjMA5nXeR7PuqIzew3SPpCV+MMvusQAcXRAxtKQlXBdqYlQ6bbI= 
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Error getting in URL which is fetched from s3 bucket.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access the URL after 300 seconds and/or your local machin's clock is off.

Comment: I think I am getting incorrect URL with function  create_presigned_url(). I check URL created with this function and manually created URL from S3 bucket both are different thats why issue is rising may be. So any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the function provided with an Alexa-hosted skill in utils.py to generate a pre-signed URL. Please note that with an Alexa-hosted skill the expiration time is fixed to 60 seconds. Even if you set the “ExpiresIn” value to 300, the skill will always consider 60 seconds.

Also, the "key" value passed to the function is not complete. When using an S3 bucket provisioned with an Alexa-hosted skill, the "key" value starts with “Media/” followed by the name of the file. For example:

```
mp3_url = create_presigned_url("Media/Trimmed_calm_music.mp3")
```

Use media files with Python (Audio file example): https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-media-files.html#audio-file-example-1